# Windows 7 installation is not finding system partition

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, ssd, bios

I've got quite a problem with my computer. I just built it today and all the parts are working, but when I select my SSD as boot drive in the Windows installer, it says "The system could not create a system partition or find an existing system partition"...

I've searched all over the web for an answer the last 2-3 hours, and tried everything from tweaking the BIOS to creating partitions via diskpart in command-promt - but nothing seems to work...

My SSD has 240 GB of space, so it should be plenty for Windows. I also have a 2TB HDD installed, but I want windows on my SSD. I am trying to install it from my 32 GB USB 3.0 stick.

I've made 2 partitions, 1 with 1 GB as system partition and 1 with the rest of the memory, labelled as Windoows. I am using UEFI BIOS, and my SSD can be found here: http://www.corsair.com/se-fi/force-series-3-240gb-sata-3-6gbps-solid-state-hard-drive

Could anyone please look into this? :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your SSD isen´t formatted to NTFS..? When you are on the install screen, click on Drive Options (advanced) (Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxM5Z.jpg). Then click on your SSD and select "Delete" from the menu below. When you have done that click on the now empty space on the harddrive, and select "New", again from the menu below. When that is done it will make several new partions, click on the largest on of them and you should be able to install Windows there.

Comment: @RasmusPeterMathieser I've allready made both a System partition and the Windows partition (the biggest one) for the OS itself. But it is not working...

Comment: Have you tried to see if you are able to install any other kind of operating system on the SSD, for example Ubuntu? I don't really have any other method of testing the state of the SSD, but my guess is that if Ubuntu wont install on it, then the SSD is physically broken. But on the other hand, if it does install, it may be that your installation media have some sort of error.

Answer (score 0):

With a live-USB with linux, format your installation disk to NTFS, after that try to run the normal installation process and it should work.

Comment: i dont know anything about linux... If it should be formatted, it ust be within the BIOS

Comment: There is a guide here on how you make a Live USB with Ubuntu Linux http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

The "system partition" is probably an [EFI System Partition (ESP).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) If the installer can't create it, then either the disk is already filled with partitions or the disk already has a partition table on it that's *not* a [GUID Partition Table (GPT).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) I'm not very familiar with the stock Windows tools for partitioning, so I can't provide you with a step-by-step guide to using your Windows installer to set up your partitions. If you care to move the disk to another computer, though, you could install my [`gdisk` utility](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) and use it to set up the partitions. (Note that `gdisk` sets up the partitions, but not the filesystems they contain; thus, you'll need to "format" the partitions using some other tool.) There are lots of other ways to achieve the same end; I'm just mentioning `gdisk` because I'm familiar with it, and with [its documentation.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html)